# Turn off scientific notation before writing to file

Tags: r, csv

My `data.frame` uses the scientific notation, when parsing files like `3.007530e+07`.

I definitely like to use it in R, however, for this analysis I have to transfer my data to csv and open it in excel(German Version), which cannot handle this notation.

My df looks sth like that:

```
df <- c(6.402000e+05,9.312903e+05,1.007800e+06,1.142000e+06,1.298500e+06,1.511700e+06,1.749000e+06,1.869357e+06)
```

I tried changing my global options such as `options(scipen=999)`, which does not work, because then I have problems with my `fread` function.

Therefore, my question:

How to change the notation in a `data.frame` before, using `write.csv()`?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: What kind of problem do you have with `fread`? For your sample data setting `scipen` works fine for me and as you want it to work.

Comment: I can't reproduce this at all. `df <- c(6.402000e+05,9.312903e+05,1.007800e+06,1.142000e+06,1.298500e+06,1.511700e+06,1.749000e+06,1.869357e+06; write.csv(df, file = "tst.csv")` produces a file without scientific notation.

Comment: I get when I use `scipen` a 64bit integer coercion. This error is coming from the base64 package which fread uses.

Comment: why don't you just change your options when you want to write to csv, then change them back immediately, so that they don't interfere with `fread`?  You could even write a little function to wrap this procedure.

Comment: Consider serializing properly rather than going via error-prone csv files.  For R-to-R use cases, `saveRDS()` is excellent.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel, the OP states (for better or worse) that they need to have Excel in their pipeline ("I have to transfer my data to csv and open it in excel")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative to altering the R format (since you want to keep scientific notation in R), could you change how Excel imports your file?

For example, naming your csv file with a non-standard extension to trigger the manual importing process (import wizard), instead of automatically opening the file in the wrong format?

I tried a simple test with a csv formatted file of numbers in scientific notation, saved with a ".sci" filename.  My version of Excel launched the wizard, then imported the file and handled the scientific notation correctly [MS Excel Starter 2010, English version].

Edit: I found the reference to using an unrecognized file extension to trigger Excel's import wizard:  http://excelribbon.tips.net/T012201_Avoiding_Scientific_Notation_on_File_Imports.html

[The article suggests using .DAT, which I wouldn't use for an ASCII file, but I wanted to give credit where it's due for the idea.]